# EasyNetQ.ManagementClient for to get msg rate per queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm using EasyNetQ.ManagementClient nuget package for getting some stats on the rabbit. In the Web Management you can see the msg rates per queue[image]

But I can't get the same rates just for queues in code when using EasyNetQ.ManagementClient, is it possible to get them?

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient("http://ipadress", "guest", "guest");
var overview = managementClient.GetOverview();
var publishRate = overview.MessageStats.PublishDetails.Rate; // this is for all queues together
var queues = managementClient.GetQueues();
foreach (var q in queues)
{ 
  // q doesn't have any rates properties
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure out if there was a built-in way to do this?

Comment: @BigJoe714 no i haven't. I'm sending http requests to the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't figure this out but insted of using `EasyNetQ.ManagementClient` nuget package I do a web request to rabbit's api on `http://ipadress:15672/api/queues` and get JSON back in response with all the information that I need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was not present in the API back when you asked the question, but with latest `EasyNetQ.Management.Client` you can now query statistics per queue:

```
...
foreach (var q in queues)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine($"Rate for {q.Name} is {q.MessagesDetails.Rate}");
}
```